# Find dimension of the set of solutions to the system of equations $x' = A(t)x$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> Let $A$ be a continuous function defined on the interval $(a, b), a < b$, whose values are $n \times n$ matrices. Find dimension of the set of solutions to the system of equations $x' = A(t)x$.

I prove that the set of solutions $x'=A(t)x$ is a linear space. The solutions are of the form: $$x(t)=c_1x_1(t)+c_2x_2(t)+\dots +c_nx_n(t)$$ so I think that dimension of the set of solution is $n$. To confirm this, I'd have to prove that $c_ix_i$ form a basis, that is, they are linearly independent. But that's where my ideas end, I don't know how I could prove it.

Comment: How exactly you prove that the set of functions $x_i$ are linearly independent depends on how exactly these functions are defined. If they are defined according to $x_i(0)$, then perhaps you could  use the fact that the vectors $x_1(0),\dots,x_n(0)$ are linearly independent

Comment: @BenGrossmann I wrote the whole assignment, so I don't know if they are defined according to $x_i(0)$.

Comment: Even better then. **Define** solutions $x_1,\dots,x_n$ corresponding to the initial condition $x_i(0) = e_i$, where $e_1,\dots,e_n$ denotes the standard basis of $\Bbb R^n$. From the fact that $x_1(0),\dots,x_n(0)$ are linearly independent, it follows that $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are linearly independent.